# tip hardwire returns fcntl: Invalid argument

Tags: serial-port, connection

I am trying to connect via serial line from a FreeBSD box to a Sun Fire V210 running Solaris 8.
I have a serial line connected from the FreeBSD serial port to the Sun Serial Management port.

On the FreeBSD box (observer) I have this in `/etc/remote`:

```
hardwire:\
    :dv=/dev/usb0:br#9600:el=^C^S^Q^U^D:ie=%$:oe=^D:
```

When I do tip hardwire I get:

```
# tip hardwire
fcntl: Invalid argument
```

One note: There was a power outage that caused the FreeBSD box to be rebooted. 
Before the power outage, tip hardwire worked fine.
I do not see any files in `/var/spool/lock/`

Any help?

Comment: UPDATE:  The `fcntl: Invalid argument` error was when I was root user.

Comment: As non-root user, I got a different error:  - `tip hardwire`  `/var/spool/lock/LCK..usb0: No such file or directory`  `Can't open lock file.`  `all ports busy`